# How to destroy a cytoscape.js instance

Tags: memory-leaks, cytoscape.js

We are using cytoscape.js to render graphs in an Angular JS app and it seems to be leaking DOM nodes. A snapshot comparison in Chrome Dev Tools shows Detached DOM Trees being retained by the "instances" array in the global cytoscape object.

The cytoscape instance is created in the link function of the directive and I would like to clear these objects on the scope $destroy event. Even if I manually nullify the references to these instances, there are other global objects like the CanvasRenderer.data.container or CanvasRenderer.bindings[].target which still hold on to these elements which prevents them from being garbage collected.

My questions is: does cytoscape have a destroy() method that would free up references to these DOM elements that I could call on the angular $destroy event? OR what is the right way to get rid of these global references?

Screenshots from the Chrome Dev Tools profiler are here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6OGkJMuELQHeC01U1FBYkd4NVU&usp=drive_web

(Lack sufficient reputation for attaching images here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

(1) You can reuse your Cytoscape.js instances and associated DOM elements instead of destroying them.  You'll have better performance that way (esp. w.r.t. the DOM), and this is probably the approach you should be using anyway.  Though perhaps your choice of frameworks has limited your options in this regard.

(2) You can call the private `cytoscape.removeRegistrationForInstance(cy)`.

This issue stems from some old code that uses registrations for some compatibility as a jQuery plugin.  I'll remove it, but you can work around this for now.

Finally, please create [issues on Github](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new) for feature requests or bug reports.  Stackoverflow should only be used for help **questions** (e.g. "I don't understand this function in the API" etc.).

Comment: This issue was fixed with a snapshot fix [661](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/661)